# C++ Read specific parts of a file with start and endpoint

Tags: c++, serialization, readfile

I am serializing multiple objects and want to save the given Strings to a file. The structure is the following:

A few string and long attributes, then a variable amount of `maps<long, map<string, variant> >`. My first idea was creating one valid JSONFile but this is very hard to do (all of the maps are very big and my temporary memory is not big enough). Since I cant serialize everything together I have to do it piece by piece. I am planning on doing that and I then want to save the recieved strings to a file. Here is how it will look like:

```
{ "Name": "StackOverflow"}
{"map1": //map here}
{"map2": //map here}
```

As you can see this is not one valid JSON object but 3 valid JSONObjects in one file. Now I want to deserialize and I need to give a valid JSONObject to the deserializer. I already save `tellp()` everytime when I write a new JSONObject to file, so in this example I would have the following adresses saved: 26, endofmap1, endofmap2.

Here is what I want to do: I want to use these addresses, to extract the strings from the file I wrote to. I need one string which is from 0 to (26-1), one string from 26 to(endofmap1-1) and one string from endofmap1 to (endofmap2-1). Since these strings would be valid JSONObjects i could deserialize them without problem.

How can I do this?

Comment: If you have so much data that it won't all fit into your available memory at the same time (assuming you have a typical modern system with many GB available), then I would question the wisdom of choosing to manage the data in the filesystem directly.    Have you considered using a different mechanism such as an in-process database (e.g. SQL Server Compact, or maybe an embedded NoSQL database) instead?    A database will typically better equipped to handle the task than anything you could roll yourself.

Comment: I am very limited in that regard. I am recording values of an Observer and have to store them. Right now I have to store them serialized on the Harddrive, storing them in DataBases will come in the future but not right now. The maps are basically "buffers" which I will load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a `serialize` and `deserialize` class that you can use as part of a hierarchy.

So for instance, in rough C++ psuedo-code:

```
class Object : public serialize, deserialize {
public:
    int a;
    float b;
    Compound c;

    bool serialize(fstream& fs) {
      fs << a;
      fs << b;
      c->serialize(fs);
      fs->flush();
    }
    // same for deserialize
};

class Compound : serialize, deserialize {
public:
  map<> things;
  bool serialize(fstream& fs) {
    for(thing : things) {
      fs << thing;
    }
    fs->flush();
  }
};
```

With this you can use JSON as the file will be written as your walk the heirarchy.

**Update:**

To extract a specific string from a file you can use something like this:

```
// pass in an open stream (streams are good for unit testing!)
std::string extractString(fstream& fs) {
int location = /* the location of the start from file */;
int length = /* length of the string you want to extract */;
std::string str;
str.resize(length);
char* begin = *str.begin();

fs->seekp(location);
fs->read(begin, length);

return str;
}
```

Comment: I already have serialize methods and classes and I can not change them. Is there no way to extract a String from a file with an address where to  start and an address on where to end?

Comment: Hope it helps.  I don't have access to a C++ compiler where I work at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Based on you saying "my temporary memory is not big enough", I'm going to assume two possibilities (*though some kind of code example may help us help you!*).

**possibility one, the file is too big**

The issue you would be facing here isn't a new one - a file too large for memory, assuming your algorithm isn't buffering all the data, and your stack can handle the recursion of course.

On windows you can use the [MapViewOfFile function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366761(VS.85).aspx), the [MSDN has plenty of detail on that](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366546(v=vs.85).aspx). This function will effectively grab a "view" of a section of a file - allowing you to load enough of the file to modify only what you need, before closing and opening a view at a later offset.

If you are on a different platform, there will be similar functions.

**possibility two, you are doing too much at once**
The other option is more of a "software engineering" issue. You have so much data then when holding them in your std::maps, you run out of heap-memory.

If this is the case, you are going to need to use some clever thinking - here are some ideas!

1. Don't load all your data into the maps. wherever the data is coming from, take a CRC, Index, or Filename of the data-source. Store that information in the map, and leave the actual "big strings" on the hard disk. - This way you can load each *item* of data when you need it.

This works really well for data that needs to be sorted, or correlated.

2. Process or load your data when you need to write it. If you don't need to sort or correlate the data, why load it into a map beforehand at all? Just load each "big string" of data in sequence, then write them to the file with an ofstream.

Comment: Code wont help you because I am saving Variants of multiple Observers/Channels/Datafields and they update very frequently. I want to save the values of one Channel into one file. These values are in a map. Since the map is too big to load, i split it up into multiple maps (map1, map2 in my question). I am saving and loading these smaller maps. You wrote "Just load each big string of data in sequence then write"... This is exactly what I am doing right now. My problem is reading these strings from the file. I know where the string starts and ends but dont know how to extract the string with...

Comment: a starting and an end address.

Comment: @peter111 so the input data is coming from a single file that updates often? Is the input file itself what is too large to load?